# How to get the IAM role ARN that is attached to a Lambda using data blocks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have a module I want to build that requires the Lambda role's ARN. Currently, these lambda's and the role are being built in a different repo so I want to use data blocks to get the ARN of the role attached to the lambda.

Currently what I've been trying to do is the following:

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
  function_name = var.function_name
}
    
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "${data.aws_lambda_function.existing.role}"
}
```

Where I'll use the following:

```
allowed-principal-arns = [
  "${data.aws_iam_role.example.arn}"
]
```

However, I've been getting the following error:

> │ Error: reading IAM Role (lambda_arn): ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
> │            status code: 400, request id: ***************
> │
> │   with module.secrets_manager.data.aws_iam_role.example,
> │   on module/secrets_manager/main.tf line 5, in data "aws_iam_role" "example":
> │    5: data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
> │

Any ideas? I'm still kinda new to terraform.

Comment: Where is the IAM role resource created compared to where you are trying to use data sources?

Comment: All of the lambda resources are being created in another repo, I'm using data blocks because I'm not able to access them other than using a predefined variable holding the lambda name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `role` value returned from `data.aws_lambda_function.existing.role` is an ARN, not a role name. The data source [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_function#role) is unfortunately lacking the details of that, but the [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) requires the `role` to be an ARN, not a name, so the format returned from the data source should be an ARN also. It would also certainly explain the error message you are getting.

I think you can remove this code completely:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "${data.aws_lambda_function.existing.role}"
}
```

And just do this:

```
allowed-principal-arns = [
  data.aws_lambda_function.existing.role
]
```

---

Note, if you are just referencing a value in Terraform without doing any sort of string concatenation or anything, you don't need to wrap it in `"${ }"`, you can just reference the value directly, so for example this:

```
allowed-principal-arns = [
  "${data.aws_iam_role.example.arn}"
]
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
allowed-principal-arns = [
  data.aws_iam_role.example.arn
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. When I was reading the docs I didn't realize that the output of the data block role was an ARN and thought it was just the role name. Being new to terraform I don't know how to debug very well, which would have helped here I think.